# Xamarin.Firebase.Common not compatible with Xamarin.Firebase.Auth

Tags: c#, android, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to install 'Xamarin.Firebase.Storage.42.1021.1' so I can upload photos to my firebase database

I'm targeting 'MonoAndroid, Version=v7.1'

However, when I try to install the package I get the following

```
Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Firebase.Common' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 42.1024.0-beta1 constraint: Xamarin.Firebase.Common (= 42.1024.0-beta1)', 'Xamarin.Firebase.Storage 42.1021.1 constraint: Xamarin.Firebase.Common (= 42.1021.1)'.
```

Is there a quick fix without breaking my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may checked the `Dependencies` of [Xamarin.Firebase.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Storage/) and [Xamarin.Firebase.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth/).

According to your error message, you've installed the [Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 42.1024.0-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth/42.1024.0-beta1) package, which needs dependency `Xamarin.Firebase.Common (= 42.1024.0-beta1)`.

Try to downgrade your `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth` package to version 42.1021.1.

Comment: Yes I've downgraded to the more stable version and everything works ok